# What are the different types of Automation

Tags: automation

I am looking for:

- A general explanation of the different types/branches of automation, particularly in regard to computers and programming.
- More specifically, what type of automation would writing a program to automatically fill out an online form be considered?

I haven't been able to find a solid answer online, because most results are about types machine automation.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. It will help you craft better questions, which (hopefully) will help produce better answers.  Unfortunately, this question is off-topic and will likely be closed.  That being said, check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_automation for types of automated testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**White box = Structured based automation testing**

You know how the application works from a technical perspective. You might know the workflow (you can see into the system) ex: structure based test design to achieve 100% coverage [code coverage, decision coverage, and statement coverage-- decision tables or state transition testing]

**Black box = Dynamic based automation testing**

You don't know how the application works but you know what the expected outcome should be. (you view the software as a black box with inputs and outputs but have no knowledge of how the system or component is structured inside the box. here, the tester concentrates on what the software does, **NOT HOW** it does it. Ex: Equivalence partitioning [aka equivalence partitioning = only test one condition from each partition]

Comment: Quick Examples: black box automation = a web crawler script where it goes to web page and index it and clicks through each link to see where it leads (going to a travel booking site and clicking all the links on each page to find broken links).  white box automation = a specific transaction script like booking a flight